# Why is django query set .filter() only accepting an id / interger, when I want to filter by a field/value?

Tags: django, database, filter, model

I am new to django, creating a blog / article sharing website. I have a few databases set up, CRUD is functioning but I'm having trouble getting a bit more creative with the site. For example, on the news articles page, it lists all the articles shared by users. It states the category, the user, the title, the external link and when it was shared. Instead of just listing all of them , I would like to be able to give the user an option to filter either by user who submitted (all articles submitted by admin) or by car

I'm trying to filter a database, by the value of one of its fields. So for example I have a model News
which has fields like title, website, user, created on .

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category



class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='link_like', blank=True)
    external_link = models.URLField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

These are passed in from the user in a form when they share a news article on the website. I want to filter either by the user who submitted it, or by the category. (category is a ForeignKey relationship to another model called Article which only has 4 entries of BLOG, NEWS, RECIPE, REVIEW)

so in my views I try to use users = News.objects.filter(user='admin') , add 'users':users to the context, then in the template try to loop through users with a for loop. But it won't accept user='admin' in users or category='blog' , it only wants an id.

here is my news view with the attempted filters

```
def news(request):
    reports = News.objects.all()
    users = News.objects.filter(user='admin')
    blogs = News.objects.filter(category='blog')
    categorys = Article.objects.all()

    context = {'reports':reports, 'users':users, 'blogs':blogs, 'categorys':categorys}
    return render(request, 'news.html', context)
```

here is part of my template attempting to loop through the filtered news articles

```
      <table class="table">
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><span class="report_category">{{ users.category }}</span> from <span class="report_website">{{ users.website }}</span></p>
        <a href="{{ users.external_link }}"><p>{{ users.title }}</p></a>
        <p class="shared">Shared {{ users.created_on|timesince }} ago by <span class="user">{{ users.user }}</span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2REeb.png)

from examples I've seen online , like the W3 lesson page https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_queryset_filter.php  and this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tO1vvj70tX0&ab_channel=VeryAcademy

you should be able to just target it by giving a variable = Model.objects.filter(dbfieldname='value').
but when I try something similar like blogs = News.objects.filter(category='blog') or users = News.objects.filter(user='admin') it gives and error stating " Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'. "

I think I understand, that I should only be passing an integer into filter() so it will try to find a value based on the id. But I want to be able to filter by the field name or the value of a specific field.
Specifically I would like it to filter , so that I can show a list of news articles shared by a specific user or news articles with a specific category.
I have looked up similar queries on stackoverflow but the ones I found differed slightly form mine or were involved with trying to target by an id , not by the value.

If anyone has any advice, could you please share and let me know what I'm doing wrong. Also if its possible to explain why the filter methods work in those 2 examples, the W3 page and the youtube video.

Apologies if this is a silly question. Please and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The **`category`** keyword in your filter statement references an *instance* of the **`Article`** model you want to filter by.  To filter by a specific field in the related model, you need to use Djano's **"lookup separator"**:

```
blog_news = News.objects.filter(article__category='blog')
```

This would provide a queryset of **`News`** instances where the article category is `blog`, but **not** a queryset of **`Article`** instances.  You can reference the related article fields like so:

```
{% for news in blog_news %}
<tr>
  <td>
    <p><span class="report_category">{{ news.category.category }}</span>
    ...
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Furthermore, I would recommend using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) with your query to avoid an additional query each time you call `news.category`:

```
blog_news = News.objects.select_related('article__category').filter(article__category='blog')
```

See the [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/) for more uses of the **lookup separator**.